# Is GTK+ 3 thread safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gdk

I have an app that has multiple threads.  Some of the threads are using libraries that are built on top of the pthread API.

Reading through the docs it seems that at one time you had to call `gdk_threads_enter` and `gdk_threads_leave`.

But looking at the docs, the whole lot seems to be deprecated.  Now they are saying you need to do everything from the main thread.  But after the `main_thread` enters `gtk_main()` how am I supposed to signal that thread to e.g. refresh some widgets like a menu I'm building dynamically from another thread which pulls the menu items from a REST web service and is long running.  I assume I shouldn't just do that from the other thread according to the documentation.  Although it's guarded with a lock and still appears to work.  I do get occasional crashes and I'm not really sure if it's because of this this.

Comment: Is `GTask` is what are you looking for?

Comment: Use `g_idle_add`. Specified function will be called from main thread when it have nothing else to do. Return value controls if function will remain in idle list (and hence will be called again on next idle time) or be removed.

Comment: Thanks Keitar, I eventually found that but decided to use gtk_threads_add_timeout instead as I didn't need to call this function very often and putting a sleep in there to stop that blocks the main thread so the timer seemed more appropriate.

Comment: @Matt well yes, but timer is for regular operation, while idle could be added on demand from other threads and then be called only once per working set. It's more like callback than polling.

Answer (score 2):

Gtk:: widgets are not thread safe. So, never update Gtk::Widget inside a thread, update the widget inside a timer function which gets started on a regular period.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This could be a good answer if you flesh it out a little with some references and perhaps some example code.